# How can I convert Python 2.7+ code using format with zero length field name to 2.6 style named fields?

Tags: python, gdb, python-2.x

I'm trying to use [this code](https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer) which uses zero length field names with `format`, e.g.,

```py
return '{} is initialized'.format(self.value.type_name)
```

I am stuck using Python 2.6, which doesn't support this:

> ValueError: zero length field name in format

I would need to change the code to something like:

```py
return '{0} is initialized'.format(self.value.type_name)
```

Since there are many such instances of `format` being used in this way, is there an easy way to fix all of them?

---

I know, Python 2.6 is *old*. Unfortunately, it's the version that is embedded within the `gdb` installation I am required to use.

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a tool, are explicitly _off-topic_ as defined in the [help/on-topic] as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Edited the question to avoid any mention of "tools". Just looking for any solution to fix the code easily. It could be a Python module in PyPl, or an incantation of `sed`/`awk`, even somehow redefining the string `format` method. Anything better than modifying all the code manually.

Comment: Yes, you can't redefine `str.format` (`TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'`). I guess your best bet is to use `ast` module to parse the Python syntax tree, make the changes then generate the source code again.